# How do you decrypt a file created with openssl in ruby?

Tags: ruby, openssl

I created a file using: `echo "test" | openssl enc -aes256 -salt -a -k test`

Decryption code:

```
  def decrypt_string(b64_text, decryption_key)
    encrypted_text = Base64.decode64(b64_text)
    _header = encrypted_text[0, 8]
    salt = encrypted_text[8, 8]
    payload = encrypted_text[16..-1]

    decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc').decrypt

    d_1 = OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new(decryption_key + salt).digest
    d_2 = OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new(d_1 + decryption_key + salt).digest

    decipher.key = (d_1 + d_2)
    decipher.iv = OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new(d_2 + decryption_key + salt).digest

    decipher.update(payload) + decipher.final
  end
```

But when I call: `decrypt_string('U2FsdGVkX1+5Sar5DYmbDtze7yvHKdq/ZuZIVnkImDc=', 'test')`

I get OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: bad decrypt

I can not use external gems and do not want to make an OS call.  How do you use the built in openssl library?

Comment: Don't include answers in your own question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run your code it does not return an `OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError (bad decrypt)` error, so I think the `b64_text` variable is different to the one you posted.

Can you try running the following in your IRB:

```
str = `echo "test" | openssl enc -aes256 -salt -a -k test`
decrypt_string(str, 'test')
```

Does the error still persist?

Comment: It seems the issue is using the newer version of openssl in Ubuntu 18.
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017 vs. OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
But this step helped me chase down the issue so I accepted it